# is there any function in Hive similiar to decode in Oracle?

Tags: hive

I'm looking for a string function that works like Oracle's DECODE
Having table `tab` with a single column `col`

```
col
----
a
b
c
d
```

With a simple query:

```
select decode(col,'a',1,'b',2',9) dec from tab
```

I'd expect result like this:

```
dec
---
1
2
9
9
```

I haven't found any build-in function in Language Manual. Is there any UDF that can simulate DECODE?

I don't want to use `case` clause.

Regards
Pawel

Answer (score 7):

You could write a nested `if` statement.

**Query**:

```
select col
  , if(col='a', 1, if(col='b', 2, 9)) dec
from table
```

**Output**:

```
---------
col | dec
---------
 a     1
 b     2
 c     9
 d     9
```

Answer (score 5):

It may be easier to read and to inspect if you avoid nesting by using a flat CASE WHEN THEN expression :

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN col = 'a' THEN 1
    WHEN col = 'b' THEN 2
    ELSE 9
  END dec
FROM tab
```

Comment: I guess this is the best option, which is easily readable. A third approach is to develop an UDF in Java, but with the trade-off of maintaining a customized code.