# Convert SQL to Hive code in Decode

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying convert above piece of code to Hive code, since Hive doesn't support Decode, what would be hive equivalent code?

```
Decode(Greatest(Sum(NVL(TTL_ACPTD_CT),0)),0),0,NULL,SUM(LATE_RPT_CT))
```

Comment: decode can be easily replaced by `case` did you try it? what did you do so far?

Comment: Case Greatest(NVL(ttl_acptd_ct,0),0) when 0 then NULL  else SUM(late_rpt_cnt)  lt_cnt.  Tried this, working now, hive doesn't support greatest, so removing greatest wont effect output?

Comment: hive 1.1 supports greatest. you can use nexr's greatest (https://github.com/nexr/hive-udf) or simply change it to `if` or `case` also

Comment: Thanks dimamah, we r using hive 0.13 that doesn't support greatest,

Comment: great. if this helped you can upvote my comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there any function in Hive similiar to decode in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556112/is-there-any-function-in-hive-similiar-to-decode-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

All the functions you used are supported in Hive except Decode.

The workaround query would be like this:

```
case Greatest(Sum(NVL(TTL_ACPTD_CT,0)),0) when '0' then 'NULL' else SUM(LATE_RPT_CT) end as result
```

Try this, it should work.