# DECODE function in Hive in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, hive

Can someone please help to convert below query of `Oracle` in `Hive`?

```
select * 
  from tbl_my_details a 
 where decode(a.my_code,'ALL','99','01','01','02','02','03','03','04','04','06','06',
                 'Other') = a.my_content
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there any function in Hive similiar to decode in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556112/is-there-any-function-in-hive-similiar-to-decode-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `case..when` structure as follows :

```
select *
  from tbl_my_details a
 where (
        case 
        when a.my_code = 'ALL' then '99'
        when a.my_code in ('01','02','03','04','06') then a.my_code
        else 'Other'
        end 
       ) = a.my_content;
```

Answer (score 1):

In either database, simple boolean logic is preferable:

```
select * 
from tbl_my_details a 
where (a.my_code in ('01', '02', '03', '04', '06') and a.my_content = a.my_code) or
      (a.my_code = 'ALL' and a.my_content = '99') or
      (a.my_code not in ('01', '02', '03', '04', '06', 'ALL') and a.my_content = 'Other')
```