# Decode function failure in hive 1.1.0

Tags: hive, hiveql

I tried to perform conversion with decode function in hive 1.1.0.But it is throwing error.I have referred the syntax from hive functions, but still I'm getting error from decode function.Always I'm getting

> SemanticException Decode() requires exactly two arguments

```
hive> select * from tbl_test;
OK
1       aaaa
2       bbbb
3       cccc
4       dddd
Time taken: 0.12 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
hive> select decode(col1,1,'hi','hello') from tbl_test;
```

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10015]: Line 1:7 Arguments length
>   mismatch ''hello'': Decode() requires exactly two arguments

```
hive> select decode(col1,1,'hi',null) from tbl_test;
```

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10015]: Line 1:7 Arguments length
>   mismatch 'TOK_NULL': Decode() requires exactly two arguments

```
hive> select decode(col1,1,'hi') from tbl_test;
```

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10015]: Line 1:7 Arguments length
>   mismatch ''hi'': Decode() requires exactly two arguments

```
hive> select decode(col1,1,'hi',"hello") from tbl_test;
```

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10015]: Line 1:7 Arguments length
>   mismatch '"hello"': Decode() requires exactly two arguments

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556112/is-there-any-function-in-hive-similiar-to-decode-in-oracle ?

Comment: This  question is different  than the above link.

Comment: If you have referred the syntax from hive functions, you should know that function arguments are decode(binary bin, string charset)  and it is for decoding binary to string using charset specified.

Answer (score 1):

[decode function in Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#String+Functions) is not the same as decode function in Oracle.

Use `case` or `if` [conditional statement](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions):

```
select case col1 when 1 then 'hi' else 'hello' end from tbl_test;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,but I need to perform this query only through decode function.

Comment: @user2733125 Decode function signature in Hive is `decode(binary bin, string charset)` - Decodes the first argument into a String using the provided character set. Opposite to binary encode(string src, string charset). This seems completely different of  what you want